# Redirection problem with odoo on debian 11

Tags: nginx, odoo, debian

I have a problem with my Odoo installation. Every time I connect to it or go to a different page, instead of redirecting me to my site (odoo.thelightguardian.fr) it redirects me to an invalid site: http://odoo/web. I can't solve this problem.

I'm working with Debian 11

```
upstream odooserver {
 server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}

# http to https redirection
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name odoo.thelightguardian.fr;
    return 301 https://odoo.thelightguardian.fr$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name odoo.thelightguardian.fr;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo_error.log;
   
   # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/odoo.thelightguardian.fr/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/odoo.thelightguardian.fr/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/odoo.thelightguardian.fr/chain.pem;


    # Proxy settings
    proxy_read_timeout 720s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
    proxy_send_timeout 720s;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    # Request for root domain
    location / {
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_pass http://odooserver;
    }

    # Cache static files
    location ~* /web/static/ {
        proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
        proxy_buffering on;
        expires 864000;
        proxy_pass http://odooserver;
    }

    # Gzip Compression
    gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
    gzip on;
}
```

I have tried various solutions using ChatGPT for example and other solutions from different forums but none of them solves my problem.

Comment: Look into Odoo's system parameters for the key `web.base.url`, what is the value?

Comment: @CZoellner Here is the value:

`web.base.url = odoo.thelightguardian.fr`

Comment: that should be ok, no idea, hopefully the nginx experts can help :/

Answer (score 0):

Edit your odoo config file and add the line

```
proxy_mode = True
```

Then restart odoo server